# Trying to update Facebook Open Graph meta tags using client side jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I use ajax to render a content page with a Facebook Like Button plugin in it.

The problem is that when the user clics Like, Facebook will extract meta info but I don't know how to assign the meta with ajax.

I tried using append to head int FB.init but it seems to not work and the update isn't reflected when users like the page on Facebook

`$('head').append("<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>');`

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but why do you need to do that? you can set and change the meta tags from server-side while building the markup...

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that facebook like will extract meta info but I don't know how to assign the meta with ajax.
>
> I tried use append to head int FB.init but it seems not work.

**Of course** this does not work, because Facebook’s scraper requests your URLs from your *server* – and does not care about what the DOM might currently look like in any user’s *browser*.

You **can not** add Open Graph meta data client-side.

Comment: My understanding FB will respect Open Graph meta tags.

Comment: @santa: I did not say they didn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use such script:

```
/// Append Meta tags
function setMT(metaName, name, value) {
        var t = 'meta['+metaName+'='+name+']';
        var mt = $(t);
        if (mt.length === 0) {
            t = '<meta '+metaName+'="'+name+'" />';
            mt = $(t).appendTo('head');
        }
        mt.attr('content', value);
    }
```

and call this function from body:

```
setMT('property', 'og:title', 'Title for Facebook');
```

I have similar on the News Site at http://www.livepage.info

Answer (score 0):

be careful with using '[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)'. 
According to the JQuery [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/), this method has a move effect (reads from source, copies to destination and removes the source).

A theoretical way is something like this:

```
headObj = $("head");
keywordObj = $(headObj).find("meta[name='keywords']");
newKeywords = $(keywordObj).attr("content");
newKeywords += myKeywords; 
$(keywordObj).attr("content", newKeywords);
```

Download and install the plugin FireBug for browser FireFox, so you can check the changes at runtime.