# Add og: meta info for Facebook after Ajax load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

Our website [www.theshinebox.com](http://www.theshinebox.com/) loads individual posts via AJAX, we'd like to be able to share/like individual pages, but since the main page has been loaded, the  has already been established and facebook is pulling from here.

Is there a way to add info to the `<head>` after the AJAX page load?  I came across this, but it didn't seem to work for me:

[Trying to update Facebook Open Graph meta tags using client side jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167759/use-jquery-and-ajax-to-add-facebook-meta-tag/5653131#5653131)

Answer (score 2):

In general, "NO".  You should be using server-side code to generate appropriate meta tags for each page.

Facebook isn't going to parse the HTML source of the page currently loaded in your browser window.  It will take the URL you give it, make an HTTP request to that URL, and parse the meta tags in the HTTP response.

You might be able to adjust the URL that you will share on Facebook via Javascript/AJAX, but that URL still needs to have the right meta tags when Facebook makes HTTP request to it.