# Loading via AJAX a facebook Like button that uses Open Graph tags

Tags: ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use jquery and ajax to add facebook meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167759/use-jquery-and-ajax-to-add-facebook-meta-tag)

in my website I have a set of items laid out on a grid.
Clicking an item loads its detail via AJAX. In the detail view I have a product title, picture, description.

In this view I want a Like button, which of course should trigger a Like on the content loaded via AJAX. **(N.B.: this content can also be accessed without AJAX)**

If one does not need to specify the title and picture to share, this is trivial: just include in the detail view an fb:like tag with the appropriate value in the href attribute.

However I need also the picture and title, which are specified using OpenGraph tags.

These tags need to have different values depending on the item that was clicked.

This is the solution I tried:

- As in the docs, the JS SDK is loaded asynchronously in the homepage and FB.init is called there too ( **with parse : false** )
- *head* contains the OG tags with *title*, *url*, and *image* values appropriate for the homepage
- When a product's detail is loaded via AJAX, I include in the response some JS ( see the code snippet below ) that updates the og tags to give them the values referring to the product

  - Finally, I call FB.XFBML.parse()

The result I obtain is that the OG tags in  are updated perfectly, **before** FB.XFBML.parse() is called.
However pressing the Like button creates a 'like' for the homepage, **as if the FB.init call is keeping the previous values of the OG tags and ignoring the current values I set via JS**

I looked at lots of questions both here and on Google in general, but surprisingly enough I could not find a case similar to this one.

Here is my call to FB.init

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      channelUrl : '*correct value hidden for privacy*', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : false  // I want to parse them once the OG tags are properly set
    });

    // No additional code after init in my case
  };
```

This is the JS I put in the AJAX response, right after the HTML to insert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    og_tags( <?php echo CJavaScript::encode( $this->shareData() ); ?> );        
    $(document).ready( function() {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    });
</script>
```

Here are the functions' definitions

```
function og_tags( params ) {
    var head = $('head');
    for ( var p in params )
        place_og_tag( { 'name' : p, 'value' : params[p] }, head );
}

function place_og_tag( opts, head ) {
    var name = "og:" + opts.name;
    var $tag = $( 'meta[property="' + name + '"]', head );
    if ( $tag.length == 0 )
        head.append( $('<meta property="' + name + '" content="' + opts.value + '" />') );
    else
        $tag.attr('content', opts.value );
}
```

Help is really appreciated as I've been struggling with this for days.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5167759/use-jquery-and-ajax-to-add-facebook-meta-tag/13084293#13084293 | Just point the Like button to the URL of the page that displays the item “stand-alone” without any AJAX.

Comment: Man, you are a life saver! It's just so disturbing that in the docs for FB.XFBML.parse() they do not simply state that the parsing triggers the scraper on the url in the href. Again, thank you!