# Facebook Like: Dynamically setting og:title property with JS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to update Facebook Open Graph meta tags using client side jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167759/trying-to-update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-using-client-side-jquery-and-ajax)

I have an AJAX-driven single page search, with like button for each recommendation.
I use `FB.XFBML.parse();` to parse like button code on the fly.

But I also need to give each recommendation a different title to be shown in facebook.
I use the `og:title` property and manipulate it on the fly to match the current recommendation. So inside my `<head>` I have:

```
<meta id="fb_title" content="Something" property="og:title">
```

And in my script:

```
$("#fb_title").attr("content",recommendation.title);
```

Although the `content` attribute is changed as expected, it is not being rendered by FB and I keep getting the original value that was sent from the server (Obviously I use `FB.XFBML.parse();` after I manipulate `og:title`). Is it possible to tell FB to re-render it?

Comment: So is it impossible to achieve? even with AJAX?

Comment: check [this post][1] may be it'll be helpful for you


  [1]: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10256892/mvc3-meta-tag-dynamically-change

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a method to re-render on the client-side