# How to edit content attribute in html meta tags?

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

I am using  the following code to edit the "content" attribute into a meta data element:

```
$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", my_title_var);
$("meta[property='og\\:description']").attr("content", my_desc_var);
```

This is my html code:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="" />
 <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
```

When I inspect the html code the result of javascript code is ok, but when I try to share my webpage via FaceBook or Google+, It seems not working and the Social Network are not able to take my webpage data (title and descrpition) correclty.

Wrinting manually the meta content attribute instead the Social Network takes my webapge data correctly, in this way:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="My title" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="My description"/>
```

This works.

Is there some better ways to edit the contet attribute into html meta tags element using javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167759/trying-to-update-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags-using-client-side-jquery-and-ajax/13084293#13084293

Answer (score 0):

Javascript run after the HTML is created, so if some page load your HTML and search for some tags that you create by Javascript, then that page will never find it...